# Magento Trying to display {{block type="catalog/product_list" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}} on homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, template, wysiwyg

Hi I am trying to display the current block

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Using the CMS Wysiwg for my home page. I have set the permissions to display the block to yes but it will still not output anything?

If i add text to wysiwyg i can see the text but it's not outputting my template?

Just to add this was working before i used fooman speedster?

Answer (score 0):

Please allow permission for **'catalog/product_list**' block from '**System**-**>Permissions**->**Blocks**'

[image]